# finding values in a different column of a different sheet then pasting it to the orignial sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a value in cell b3 of sheet Lookup, I want to find if that value in sheet Data, range B2:B11302, when that value is found, I want to jump over to one cell to the right, copy that value then paste it in cell b8 in sheet Lookup again. I am using the following code but I keep getting run-time error 1004. Please help!

```
Sub lookupval1()



Dim j As Long
Dim clid As String
Dim n As Integer
Dim k As Long
Dim m As Long
Dim pol_num As Range



clid = Sheets("Lookup").Range("c3")



j = 1
k = 1
m = 1

Do Until Sheets("Data").Range("b2").Offset(j - 1, 0) = ""


    If clid = Sheets("Data").Range("b2").Offset(j - 1, 0) Then
        Sheets("Lookup").Range("b8").Value = Sheets("Data").Range("b2").Offset(j - 1, 0).Select
    Else

    End If

    j = j + 1

Loop



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the .Select from

```
 Sheets("Lookup").Range("b8").Value = Sheets("Data").Range("b2").Offset(j - 1, 0).Select
```

It is a method and you can't use it at the same time as you are trying to use its value in an assignment.

So maybe try something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub lookupval1()
    Dim j As Long, clid As String, n As Long, k As Long, m As Long
    clid = Sheets("Lookup").Range("C3")
    j = 1: k = 1: m = 1

    Do Until IsEmpty(Sheets("Data").Range("B2").Offset(j - 1, 0))
        If clid = Sheets("Data").Range("B2").Offset(j - 1, 0) Then
           Sheets("Lookup").Range("B8").Value = Sheets("Data").Range("B2").Offset(j - 1, 0)
           Exit Do
        End If
        j = j + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```